# I am creating an empty Java class and compiling it, will any constructor be created

Tags: java, constructor, empty-class

I am creating an empty Java class and compiling it, will any constructor be created as it is being compiles successfully

Class ABC{

}

Comment: yes. a default constructor.

Comment: @Aominè how will it happen?

Comment: it's automatically generated by the compiler. if that doesn't answer your question then you'll need to speak with the language implementors for the low-level details. :).

Comment: if you want to check what is generated use javap

Comment: @Aominè ok thanks
And one more thing is there anything like JVM constructor in java?

Comment: If you came to this question on your own, I would recommend taking a Java programming class, if you can afford it, since this topic is usually covered. I say this because taking a course can sometimes help one reach their full potential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default constructor with no formal parameters and no throws clause is implicitly declared.

So, the compiler will put the default constructor for you if you won't put any constructors.

So your class will be like:

```
class ABC {

    public ABC() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to Java Documentation ( [Providing Constructors for Your Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) ):

> You don't have to provide any constructors for your class, but you must be careful when doing this. The compiler automatically provides a no-argument, default constructor for any class without constructors.

It will create a default constructor if no constructor is defined

Also, if we compile your ABC class and decompile the bytecode generated, we will see this code :

```java
public class ABC {
    public ABC() {
    }
}
```

So the compiled version have a default constructor